# best query for sum function in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, runtime

my query is :

```
SELECT SUM(`acctinputoctets`) , SUM(`acctoutputoctets`) 
FROM `userhistory`
WHERE `compid`    = 1
AND acctupdatetime between  DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 0 hour) 
 AND  DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 6 hour);
```

//14.9 second !!!

how to speed up run time?

Comment: Not much to go on here. Can you add your table definition an explain plan and some indication of userhistory size.

Comment: The only thing you can really do here would be to add indices on the columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a an index on compid

could be useful also a composite index  for avoid access to table eg

```
create index idx_compid on userhistory (compid, acctupdatetime, acctinputoctets, acctoutputoctets)
```

or at least a composite with all the column in where

```
create index idx_compid on userhistory (compid, acctupdatetime)
```

Comment: I have index on compid and id

Comment: i have 1 milion records.